# Can you query data by a string?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Our old ORM had the ability to pass it a model stucture via string, and it would return the requested data.

So like

.Query("User.Student.Cohort")

And it would return like 2021

or

.Query("User.Student.Name") gives "Steve"

Can EFCore do anything like this, or am I doing some refactoring :)

Comment: Out of the box - no. With some 3rd party libraries like Dynamic LINQ - yes. Better do some refactoring :) Seriously, the main benefit of EF (Core) and LINQ is to use compile time expressions rather than strings.

Comment: Yeah I didn't design it, legacy code that got dumped on my plate.  Bummer, thanks guys... refactor this crappy logic out I think then!